# What is overriding the systemwide keyboard layout settings?

Tags: keyboard-layout, home-directory, gsettings

I have

```
[org.gnome.desktop.input-sources]
sources=[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'hu')]
```

in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/99_my.gschema.overrride file. I ran `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` and now those became default settings systemwide. And whenever `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` returns `[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'hu')]`, I have 2 layouts available in the panel.

However if I empty my home directory and reboot, then all setting should fall back to the systemwide default, and that indeed happens, hence all my other setting in `99_my.gschema.override` take effect, except for that one keyboard layout setting

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us')]
```

Resetting with `gsettings` command to systemwide default causes, as desired, to have both layouts in the panel.

```
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'hu')]
```

This makes me suspect that some process (maybe `unity-settings-daemon`, maybe `indicator-keyboard-service`, ..?) overrides the systemwide default at every login.

I would report a bug, but I do not know against what. Do you know what can cause this?

**update**: Running

```
gsettings list-recursively >/tmp/01
gsettings list-schemas | xargs -n 1 gsettings reset-recursively
gsettings list-recursively >/tmp/02
diff /tmp/01 /tmp/02
```

after home-dir-clean and reboot, produces:

```
197c197
< org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '<Control><Alt>t'
---
> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '<Primary><Alt>t'
473c473
< org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '<Control><Alt>t'
---
> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '<Primary><Alt>t'
1021c1021
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Control><Alt>KP_0']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Primary><Alt>KP_0']
1027c1027
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize ['<Control><Super>Down']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize ['<Primary><Super>Down', '<Super>Down', '<Alt>F5']
1032c1032
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu ['<Super>s']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu ['<Super>s', '<Alt>F1']
1039c1039
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Right']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
1041,1042c1041,1042
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize ['<Control><Super>Up']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize ['<Primary><Super>Up', '<Super>Up', '<Primary><Alt>KP_5']
1046c1046
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally ['disabled']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally @as []
1052c1052
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Left']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
1059c1059
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower ['disabled']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower @as []
1063,1067c1063,1067
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded ['<Control><Alt>s']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 ['disabled']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded ['<Primary><Alt>s']
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 @as []
1072,1078c1072,1078
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Control><Super>d']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 ['disabled']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Primary><Super>d', '<Primary><Alt>d', '<Super>d']
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 @as []
1080,1082c1080,1082
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 ['disabled']
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 ['disabled']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 @as []
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 @as []
1084c1084
< org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Control><Alt>KP_5']
---
> org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Primary><Alt>KP_5']
1904,1905c1904,1905
< org.compiz existing-profiles ['Default', 'unity']
< org.compiz current-profile 'unity'
---
> org.compiz existing-profiles ['Default']
> org.compiz current-profile 'Default'
2144c2144
< org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'us')]
---
> org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'hu')]
2388c2388
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-3 ['disabled']
---
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-3 ['Disabled']
2390c2390
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-4 ['disabled']
---
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-4 ['Disabled']
2392,2396c2392,2396
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-8 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-9 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-12 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-1 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-10 ['disabled']
---
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-8 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-9 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-12 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-1 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-10 ['Disabled']
2412c2412
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-11 ['disabled']
---
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-11 ['Disabled']
2414,2417c2414,2417
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-5 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-6 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-7 ['disabled']
< org.compiz.integrated run-command-2 ['disabled']
---
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-5 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-6 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-7 ['Disabled']
> org.compiz.integrated run-command-2 ['Disabled']
2628c2628
< com.canonical.indicator.keyboard migrated true
---
> com.canonical.indicator.keyboard migrated false
```

i.e. the keyboard-layout setting is just one of those which get overwritten by something.

This list might reveal to some of you which process/service is the culprit.

update2: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1418939

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does your user profile give under [InputSource0] and [InputSource2] ? the file is in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`.

Comment: after cleaning home-dir only "[InputSource0] xkb=us", after resetting to sys default "[InputSource0] xkb=us [InputSource1] xkb=hu"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go through the settings menu, and do couple of things. First, open the language support menu and it should let you know whether or not the language support is installed completely. Second, open Region and Language, and under System tab, there should be an option to copy your settings to the system settings.Try doing that

[image]

Comment: Too bad an excellent answer doesn't get an acceptance, so: upvote! ;-)

Comment: @Fabby, hardly excellent answer, but thank you for the kind word and vote *bowding down humbly*

Comment: не за что... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is some component of the *Unity Destop Environment*.

I installed gnome-shell, and logged into gnome-session, ran the script in the question and the diff was empty, hence that session did not override any settings. And indeed both keyboard layouts where available in the panel.

I filed a bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1418939

Comment: that foobar is actually me I was just lazy to log in